# when dows Ubuntu automount NTFS partitions? and adding bind

Tags: ntfs, fstab

I have an NTFS partition for storing my files only and seeing them in both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10. When I boot Ubuntu I can access it with no trouble at all in /media/Archivos (it's the disk label).
I want to bind some folders in that partition to my documents, downloads, etc., folders so I use the same in both OSes.
I learned what lines to add in /etc/fstab.m ex:

/media/Archivos/Documentos /home/fede/Documentos none defaults,bind 0 0

But I edit fstab and that partition doesn't appear! Only my swap and my ext4 partitions appear in that file. So when does Ubuntu mount my other partitions, and in what file can I add the bind options I want?

Or can I add the nTFS partition to fstab and it will be mounted sooner than it is mounted now? Or will Ubuntu try to mount it twice generating an error?

Thanks!

Comment: If I remember correctly fstab started getting dynamically generated a while back.  You might look at `man automount`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to edit fstab for auto mounting. Nautilus doesn't use `fstab` for mounting devices.

To configure ntfs drives for auto mount and other changes I found **Storage Device Manager (pysdm)** is the best. You can install it from the software center.

Here is a quick [guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/how-to-mount-partitions-automatically.html) how to configure auto mount.